# Configure Nginx to reply to http://my-domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

There are numerous posts about this issue but none that solve my problem.

I am using `jwilder/nginx-proxy` as a reverse proxy and `jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` to generate certificates.

For some reason at some point the certification process stopped working. This appears to be because `/.well-known/acme-challenge/somefilename` is returning a 404.

As far as I can see this config:

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    auth_basic off;
    auth_request off;
    allow all;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri =404;
    break;
}
```

Should allow the browsing of e.g. `/usr/share/nginx/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html`, which exists inside both docker images and should be browsable at `https://headphones.my-domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html`.

When I try to see these urls I get a 404:

```
$ curl http://phpmyadmin.my-domain.com.work/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html
                                 
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.17.6</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody see from my config file why this file would not be browsable?

Here is my complete /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (generated using `nginx -T`):

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
daemon off;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;

    text/mathml                                      mml;
    text/plain                                       txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
    text/x-component                                 htc;

    image/png                                        png;
    image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
    image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
    image/webp                                       webp;
    image/x-icon                                     ico;
    image/x-jng                                      jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;

    font/woff                                        woff;
    font/woff2                                       woff2;

    application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
    application/json                                 json;
    application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
    application/msword                               doc;
    application/pdf                                  pdf;
    application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                                  rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                     pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                     xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                     docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
    application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
    application/x-cocoa                              cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                           run;
    application/x-perl                               pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
    application/x-sea                                sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
    application/x-stuffit                            sit;
    application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
    application/zip                                  zip;

    application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                         deb;
    application/octet-stream                         dmg;
    application/octet-stream                         iso img;
    application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
    audio/ogg                                        ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                                ra;

    video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                                       ts;
    video/mp4                                        mp4;
    video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                                  mov;
    video/webm                                       webm;
    video/x-flv                                      flv;
    video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
    video/x-mng                                      mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Proto, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# scheme used to connect to this server
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto {
  default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
  ''      $scheme;
}
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Port, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# server port the client connected to
map $http_x_forwarded_port $proxy_x_forwarded_port {
  default $http_x_forwarded_port;
  ''      $server_port;
}
# If we receive Upgrade, set Connection to "upgrade"; otherwise, delete any
# Connection header that may have been passed to this server
map $http_upgrade $proxy_connection {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}
# Apply fix for very long server names
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
# Default dhparam
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem;
# Set appropriate X-Forwarded-Ssl header
map $scheme $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl {
  default off;
  https on;
}
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
log_format vhost '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
access_log off;
                ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
                ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384';
                ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
resolver 192.168.1.1;
# HTTP 1.1 support
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_x_forwarded_port;
# Mitigate httpoxy attack (see README for details)
proxy_set_header Proxy "";
server {
        server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
        listen 80;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 503;
}
server {
        server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 503;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/default.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/default.key;
}
# emby.my-domain.com
upstream emby.my-domain.com {
                                ## Can be connected with "bridge" network
                        # emby
                        server 172.17.0.3:8096;
}
server {
        server_name emby.my-domain.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Do not HTTPS redirect Let'sEncrypt ACME challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                default_type "text/plain";
                break;
        }
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
        server_name emby.my-domain.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/emby.my-domain.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/emby.my-domain.com.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/emby.my-domain.com.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/emby.my-domain.com.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/emby.my-domain.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://emby.my-domain.com;
        }
}
# headphones.my-domain.com
upstream headphones.my-domain.com {
                                ## Can be connected with "bridge" network
                        # headphones
                        server 172.17.0.9:8181;
}
server {
        server_name headphones.my-domain.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Do not HTTPS redirect Let'sEncrypt ACME challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                default_type "text/plain";
                break;
        }
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
        server_name headphones.my-domain.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/headphones.my-domain.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/headphones.my-domain.com.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/headphones.my-domain.com.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/headphones.my-domain.com.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://headphones.my-domain.com;
        }
}
# homeassistant.my-domain.com
upstream homeassistant.my-domain.com {
                                ## Can be connected with "bridge" network
                        # homeassistant
                        server 172.17.0.15:8123;
}
server {
        server_name homeassistant.my-domain.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Do not HTTPS redirect Let'sEncrypt ACME challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                default_type "text/plain";
                break;
        }
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
        server_name homeassistant.my-domain.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/homeassistant.my-domain.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/homeassistant.my-domain.com.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/homeassistant.my-domain.com.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/homeassistant.my-domain.com.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://homeassistant.my-domain.com;
        }
}
# hydra.my-domain.com
upstream hydra.my-domain.com {
                                ## Can be connected with "bridge" network
                        # hydra
                        server 172.17.0.6:5075;
}
server {
        server_name hydra.my-domain.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Do not HTTPS redirect Let'sEncrypt ACME challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                default_type "text/plain";
                break;
        }
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
        server_name hydra.my-domain.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/hydra.my-domain.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/hydra.my-domain.com.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/hydra.my-domain.com.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/hydra.my-domain.com.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://hydra.my-domain.com;
        }
}
# nextcloud.my-domain.com
upstream nextcloud.my-domain.com {
                                ## Can be connected with "bridge" network
                        # nextcloud
                        server 172.17.0.17:80;
}
server {
        server_name nextcloud.my-domain.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Do not HTTPS redirect Let'sEncrypt ACME challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                default_type "text/plain";
                break;
        }
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
        server_name nextcloud.my-domain.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nextcloud.my-domain.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/nextcloud.my-domain.com.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/nextcloud.my-domain.com.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nextcloud.my-domain.com.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/nextcloud.my-domain.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://nextcloud.my-domain.com;
        }
}
# nzbget.my-domain.com
upstream nzbget.my-domain.com {
                                ## Can be connected with "bridge" network
                        # nzbget
                        server 172.17.0.4:6789;
}
server {
        server_name nzbget.my-domain.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Do not HTTPS redirect Let'sEncrypt ACME challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                default_type "text/plain";
                break;
        }
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
        server_name nzbget.my-domain.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nzbget.my-domain.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/nzbget.my-domain.com.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/nzbget.my-domain.com.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nzbget.my-domain.com.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/nzbget.my-domain.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://nzbget.my-domain.com;
        }
}
# organizr.my-domain.com
upstream organizr.my-domain.com {
                                ## Can be connected with "bridge" network
                        # organizr
                        server 172.17.0.10:80;
}
server {
        server_name organizr.my-domain.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Do not HTTPS redirect Let'sEncrypt ACME challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                default_type "text/plain";
                break;
        }
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
        server_name organizr.my-domain.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/organizr.my-domain.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/organizr.my-domain.com.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/organizr.my-domain.com.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/organizr.my-domain.com.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://organizr.my-domain.com;
        }
}
# phpmyadmin.my-domain.com
upstream phpmyadmin.my-domain.com {
                                ## Can be connected with "bridge" network
                        # phpmyadmin
                        server 172.17.0.16:80;
}
server {
        server_name phpmyadmin.my-domain.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Do not HTTPS redirect Let'sEncrypt ACME challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                default_type "text/plain";
                break;
        }
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
        server_name phpmyadmin.my-domain.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/phpmyadmin.my-domain.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/phpmyadmin.my-domain.com.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/phpmyadmin.my-domain.com.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/phpmyadmin.my-domain.com.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://phpmyadmin.my-domain.com;
        }
}
# portainer.my-domain.com
upstream portainer.my-domain.com {
                                ## Can be connected with "bridge" network
                        # portainer
                        server 172.17.0.2:9000;
}
server {
        server_name portainer.my-domain.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Do not HTTPS redirect Let'sEncrypt ACME challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                default_type "text/plain";
                break;
        }
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
        server_name portainer.my-domain.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/portainer.my-domain.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/portainer.my-domain.com.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/portainer.my-domain.com.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/portainer.my-domain.com.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://portainer.my-domain.com;
        }
}
# radarr.my-domain.com
upstream radarr.my-domain.com {
                                ## Can be connected with "bridge" network
                        # radarr
                        server 172.17.0.11:7878;
}
server {
        server_name radarr.my-domain.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Do not HTTPS redirect Let'sEncrypt ACME challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                default_type "text/plain";
                break;
        }
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
        server_name radarr.my-domain.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/radarr.my-domain.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/radarr.my-domain.com.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/radarr.my-domain.com.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/radarr.my-domain.com.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://radarr.my-domain.com;
        }
}
# sonarr.my-domain.com
upstream sonarr.my-domain.com {
                                ## Can be connected with "bridge" network
                        # sonarr
                        server 172.17.0.8:8989;
}
server {
        server_name sonarr.my-domain.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Do not HTTPS redirect Let'sEncrypt ACME challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                default_type "text/plain";
                break;
        }
        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}
server {
        server_name sonarr.my-domain.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/sonarr.my-domain.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/sonarr.my-domain.com.key;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/sonarr.my-domain.com.dhparam.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/sonarr.my-domain.com.chain.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://sonarr.my-domain.com;
        }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/vhost.d/emby.my-domain.com:
client_max_body_size 50M;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default:
## Start of configuration add by letsencrypt container
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    auth_basic off;
    auth_request off;
    allow all;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri =404;
    break;
}
## End of configuration add by letsencrypt container
proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
proxy_hide_header Content-Security-Policy;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/vhost.d/nextcloud.my-domain.com:
rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/dav redirect;
rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/dav redirect;
proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
proxy_hide_header Content-Security-Policy;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/vhost.d/nzbget.my-domain.com:
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

Comment: Any messages in the error log? Are the file permissions correct for each of the directories in the path?

Comment: There were no permissions issues or error messages apart from the 404 when I tried to view the test files (and when letsencrypt was trying to use the same path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anybody else has this issue I have fixed it by removing containers, config files AND IMAGES and then recreating them... here is the process for those that have a setup similar to mine:

```
// Stop and remove the containers and images
docker stop nginx-proxy-letsencrypt
docker stop reverseproxy
docker rm nginx-proxy-letsencrypt
docker rm reverseproxy
docker rmi jwilder/nginx-proxy
docker rmi jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
```

```sh
# Backup config files
mv /mnt/data/config/reverseproxy /mnt/data/config/reverseproxy.old
```

```sh
# Create and start the reverse proxy
docker run -d \
    --name=reverseproxy \
    -e DEFAULT_HOST=pihole.my-domain.com \
    -p 80:80 \
    -p 443:443 \
    -v /mnt/data/config/reverseproxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs \
    -v /mnt/data/config/reverseproxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d \
    -v /mnt/data/config/reverseproxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html \
    -v /mnt/data/config/reverseproxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d \
    -v /mnt/data/config/reverseproxy/dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro \
    --log-opt max-size=50m \
    --restart=unless-stopped \
    jwilder/nginx-proxy

docker start reverseproxy
```

```sh
# Create and start the reverse proxy companion
docker run -d \
    --name nginx-proxy-letsencrypt \
    --volumes-from reverseproxy \
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
    --restart=unless-stopped \
    jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

docker start nginx-proxy-letsencrypt
docker logs -f nginx-proxy-letsencrypt
```

Now wait until all relevant certificates have been created. Press ctrl+c to exit the log output and you are good to go.